# Unable to append list of strings to empty dataframe in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of 15 field names as strings, called `field_list`. I also have a list of 15 values that are each strings, called `value_list`. I want to create a dataframe that uses the strings from `field_list` as the column headers, and then appends values to each of those columns by appending the values from `value_list`, all in order.

This seemed like it could be easily carried out with:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data=value_list, columns=field_list`
```

However, this just results in this error:`ValueError: Shape of passed values is (15, 1), indices imply (15, 15)`

This is confusing me, because I am just passing a list of values that should be added to the empty dataframe as a row of values. How can I fix my code so that the correct shape is passed?

Comment: `data` must be 2D. Try `pd.DataFrame(data=[value_list], columns=field_list)`

Comment: Solved! Thanks!